# Ошибка использования using(void method())

Tags: c#, ооп, static, c#-7.0

Не могу понять ошибки в строке - `using(Timer.Start())`

```
using System;


namespace Memory.Timers
{
    public class Timer : IDisposable
    {
        public Timer t1 = new Timer();
        private bool disposed = false;


        public void Start()
        {
            t1.Start();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            t1.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public class Class
    {
        public void WorkInSimplestCase()
        {
            using(Timer.Start())  //Ошибка 1 -
                                    An object reference is required for 
                                    the non-static field...
                                  //Ошибка 2 -
                                    'void': type used in a using 
                                    statement must be implicitly 
                                    convertible to 'System.IDisposable*

            {
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Насколько я понял, компилятор пишет, что нужен `Disposable` в классе, хотя он у меня есть. И требует нестатические методы и поля, хотя они у меня и так нестатические.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Почитайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) об использовании конструкции `using`.

В вашем случае код должен выглядеть так:

```
using(var timer = new Timer())
{
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Добавлю, что немного странно запускать таймер, и тут же его уничтожать.

Comment: @maxwell нет) По заданию таймер должен использоваться именно так) Без нового экземпляра.

Comment: @ValentineLobanoff, Значит метод `Start` должен быть статическим и возвращать `IDisposable`.

Comment: @maxwell Спасибо попробую.